# VBA EXCEL SQL CREATE TABLE syntax

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Can someone please help me with the following line. I am trying to create a table that will have a column with the Id that automatically increments when a record is inserted. This is for microsoft access.

```
"CREATE TABLE " & tblName & " ([P_Id] integer not null AUTOINCREMENT(100, 5))"
```

Comment: This is a microsoft access database.

Comment: Missed that.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: The following command doesn't work from w3schools.com                                                      .Execute "CREATE TABLE " & tblName & " ([P_Id] PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to create an MS Access table with an auto-number field:

```
"CREATE TABLE [" & tblName & "] ([P_Id] integer not null IDENTITY)"
```

I do not know if you can specify a start-value and increment, but you can try it.

Comment: Hi Mike, I know you are new to SO, but when you receive a correct answer you should "accept" the answer. This will increase your "accept percentage" and add 2 points to your reputation.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I am new. I was amazed at how fast I got answers. It was almost like everyone was just waiting for me to ask a question. How do I see the tags that I may be able to contribute?

Comment: SO is remarkable. I strongly suggest you read and digest the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq).